# Copy number file format Issue

Tags: python, r, format

I have a problem with a `.csv` file from Copy number data. The original looks like this:

```
genes               Log2
PIK3CA,TET2          -0.35
MLH2,NRAS            0.54
```

And, what I need is:

```
genes                Log2

PIK3CA              -0.35
TET2                -0.35
MLH2                0.54
NRAS                0.54
```

I have tried many things by now, and they have not been successful. The file was created with CNVkit  from gastric cancer samples. The file is much bigger, and the list of genes is longer, but this is essentially what I need to do in order to analyze our cnv data.

I have tried this:

```
awk -F , -v OFS='\t' 'NR == 1 || $0 > 0 {print $4}' copynumber.csv | less
```

Which is the closest i've got.

I use Linux, Ubuntu 16.04. I would appreciate if you could help me with an R or Python script, but, by now, any solution would be good.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `separate_rows` from the `tidyr` package if you are using R.

```
library(tidyr)

dat2 <- dat %>% separate_rows(genes)
dat2
#    genes  Log2
# 1 PIK3CA -0.35
# 2   TET2 -0.35
# 3   MLH2  0.54
# 4   NRAS  0.54
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "genes               Log2
PIK3CA,TET2          -0.35
                  MLH2,NRAS            0.54",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Or with `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`

Comment: Thanks! I think I should add this to my question: Ok, well, the original file is .cns, it is a text file, that looks like this (first line plus header):

chromosome,start,end,gene,log2 chr1,13402,861395,"LOC102725121,DDX11L1,OR4F5,LOC100133331,LOC100132062,LOC100132287,LOC100133331,LINC00115,SAMD11",-0.28067

We transformed it to a .csv so we could separate it by tab. The .cns is separated by commas but genes are a single string delimited by quotes. I hope this is more useful

Comment: @Jimena_Par Looks like a different question to me. Please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily achieved with python.
You can split a line by a space first and then 
iterate over multiple comma-separated fields.

```
filename = 'copynumber.csv'
with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
    header = fp.readline()
    print(header)
    for line in fp:
        keys, value = line.split()
        for key in keys.split(','):
            print(key + " " + value)
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been told that i am not being specific, so... I think this needs to be added to the explanation:  Ok, well, the original file is .cns, it is a text file, that looks like this (first line plus header):

chromosome,start,end,gene,log2 chr1,13402,861395,"LOC102725121,DDX11L1,OR4F5,LOC100133331,LOC100132062,LOC100132287,LOC100133331,LINC00115,SAMD11",-0.28067

We transformed it to a .csv so we could separate it by tab. The .cns is separated by commas but genes are a single string delimited by quotes. I hope this is more useful

Comment: @Jimena_Par, please edit your question instead. The text in the comments is poorly formatted.